# Hybrid Architecture of Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to setup the Architecture of SharePoint 2016 along with SharePoint Online (Hybrid). Can someone please help me out in creating the use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at: `"https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957480.aspx#Set up SharePoint services for hybrid"`?  This article and the hybrid BLOG "`https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/beyondsharepoint/2016/08/12/hybrid-configuration-wizard/`" are great resources.